# number of executions in an algorithm

Tags: execution

For this algorithm:

```
       i = 1
       while(i<=2n){
       x = x + 1
       i = i + 2
       }
```

can someone tell me how to find the formula for the number of times x = x + 1 is executed?

Comment: It would be useful to know what you have tried that did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`i` goes from `1` to `2n` (inclusive), so first thought is `2n`.
But we see that `i` increments by *two* at a time instead of one, so it's half of that: `n`.

Answer (score 0):

With  n<1 number of times executed=0.
With  n>=1 number of times executed=n.